# Output as expected using sharepoint online management shell but not with Azure Pipeline- Add Boolean Column with "True" Default Value

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I want to add a column "IsActive" and set boolean value to "true". 
Here is my code:

```
Add-PnPField -List $pagesLib -Type Boolean -InternalName "IsActive" -DisplayName "Is Active" -Group "ABC Connect Columns" -AddToDefaultView
Set-PnPField -List $pagesLib -Identity "IsActive"  -Values @{DefaultValue="1"}
```

I have used below code as well. But its not showing as expected output in Azure Pipeline

```
Add-PnPField -List $pagesLib -Type Boolean -InternalName "IsActive" -DisplayName "Is Active" -Group "ABC Connect Columns" -AddToDefaultView 
$field = Get-PnPField -List $pagesLib -Identity "IsActive"
$field.DefaultValue = "1"
$field.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```

SO, I can see "IsActive" Coulmn to true if i use Sharepoint Online Management Shell. But i need to use only Azure Pipeline.
If anyone can help on this to make it work using azure pipline that would be great.

Comment: Issue is resolved now. In visual studio i did not check in my code and azure pipeline only check in code as a script so once i check in i can see expected output.

Comment: Since you have solved the issue by yourself, could you please post your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved now. In visual studio i did not check-in my code and azure pipeline refer only check-in code as a script so once i check-in i can see expected output.